# Can you change layer parameters in a loaded caffe network?

Tags: c++, caffe

I would like to edit a layer parameter of a caffe network that has already been loaded. More specifically, I would like to edit the 'dropout_ratio' param of a dropout layer after the network is loaded and then run a forward pass.

My current issues are:
1) How do I access the params of a specific layer?
2) If I can access the params of a specific layer, how can I change them?

My dropout layer in my deploy.prototxt looks like this:

```
layer {
  name: "drop"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.1
  }
}
```

Here is a rough example of something I've tried to no avail:

```cpp
// Say the index of my dropout layer is '3'
int index = 3;
// Change the 'dropout_ratio' param to 0.5
net_->layers()[index]->dropout_params().dropout_ratio = 0.5;
// Continue as needed
```

Ideally I would like to do something like this to run the network with a custom dropout ratio, even though it is '0.1' in the deploy.prototxt. Is this something that is possible?

Additional Data: I have modified caffe's dropout layer so that dropout is always active- even during testing. The idea behind this experiment is to test the trained network with multiple 'dropout_ratio' values without creating different deploy.prototxt files

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you'd like to run test on a pretrained network?  The default functionality of the dropout layer at test time is (for lack of a better term), "no dropout".  so at test time for the Dropout layer input = output.  

Documentation: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1DropoutLayer.html

Comment: Yes, I'd like to run a test on a pre-trained network. I modified the dropout_layer.cpp and dropout_layer.cu files to always enable dropout. The idea behind this is to run a few forward passed with dropout enabled and use the standard deviation of them for confidence metrics. With that being said, I'd like to run a forward pass with different dropout_ratio values without creating new deploy.prototxt files..

Comment: I've got no firsthand experience with the c++ implementation of caffe, but in pycaffe (to my knowledge), train/test phases rely on the writing out of a prototxt in order to execute.

More clearly in this case, you should be able to directly modify the prototxt so the dropout_ratio is 0.5, load your caffemodel and this modified prototxt, and it should work.